# assoc with argument clojure

Tags: clojure, hashmap

If I have an hash-map and I want to assoc a value to it, and I get the key as an argument, what should i do?

```
 (defn define [name type kind]  "define new var in one of the tables"
(if (or (= type "static") (= type "field"))
   (def classScope (assoc classScope name (list type kind (addCount kind))))
   (def methodScope (assoc methodScope name (list type kind (addCount kind))))
     )
   )
```

My problem is that i can't use `:name`, and not `'name`.
Thanks!!

Comment: You have a number of curious constructs. First it is generally not necessary/desirable  to `def` in the middle of a function. Secondly, `assoc` is likely to complain as you are using a var potentially not yet interned. Describe your use case with a bit more detail, provide sample data and what you have tried.

Comment: I'm trying to create an hash-map that's like a symbol table: I will identify each variable by it's name, and it will have a list with its type, kind and index in the code.
in roder to add a variable to the table, I have define the function 'define', who get the variable's name, kind, and type.

Comment: my problem is that I want to use the content of name, for example "abc" as a key, but cant use `name` because i will get `abc` and not `:abc`.  and of course I cant use `:name`, because I'll get `:name` and not `:abc`.
any idea?

Comment: You can pass the function `keyword` a string and it will make it so. Maps can also use strings as keys.

Comment: great, it works! thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

Update: If you want your keys to be in keyword form, just call `keyword` on them....

```
(defn my-map-fn [name type kind]
  (assoc some-map (keyword name) (some-fn type kind)))
```

e.g.

```
(my-map-fn "some-name" "some-type" "some-kind") => {:some-name some-val}
```

**Note** that you shouldn't use def inside of defn. It looks like you want to keep a map of data and as you call `define` you want to store some more data in that map. A way that I go about this is to use atoms (there are other ways too).

```
(defonce classScope (atom {})
(defonce methodScope (atom {}))

(defn define 
  "if you want a doc string it goes here"
  [name type kind]
  (swap! (if (#{"static" "field"} type) classScope methodScope)
         #(assoc % name (list type kind (addCount kind)))))
```

the benefit here is you get atomic updates and calls to `define` that may happen really close together won't butt heads.

Comment: `swap!` and `assoc` participate in the unified update model, so rather than building this lambda yourself it is nicer to write `(swap! (if ...) assoc name [type kind (addCount kind)])`

Comment: that's not my problem.. I know i shouldn't use define over and over again but that's not the point-
the problem is how to add a new key that identified by argument- in this case, name. if name has the val "hello" i want it to be `:hello`, but by writing it as `name` (in the assoc function) you will not find it, it wiil be {hello (a b)} for ex. and if I will write `:name` it will be {:name (a b )}, and that's my problem.

Comment: @ReutSchremer `(keyword name)` is what you want then... I'll update the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Let's start with your explanatory comment:

> I'm trying to create an hash-map that's like a symbol table: I will
>   identify each variable by its *name*, and it will have a list with its
>   *type*, *kind* and *index* in the code.

A few thoughts:

- Don't use a *list* for the variable's characteristics; use a *map*.
- You can think of the name of a variable as

  - a plain old string
  - a symbol
  - a keyword

  Any of these works as the key of a map entry. Keep it simple. Use a string.
- You're going to need such a table for every scope. And a scope should know its enclosing scope.
- The descriptors *static* and *field* are not types; nor are they
  alternatives in - say - Java.

I suggest you look at [clojure.spec](https://clojure.org/about/spec) and [typed Clojure](https://github.com/clojure/core.typed/wiki/User-Guide) to see how similar problems are handled within Clojure.